# Bootstrap navbar left side content gets disappeared on reducing the window size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

The problem is that the left content in the navigation bar gets disappeared when reducing the window size. I tried using the `row` and `column` (`column-sm and column-xs-`) class the fix the problem but it is still there.

I am also attaching the images of the bar.

In the First image the screen size is maximized
[image]

In the Second image the screen size is reduced

[image]

So I want that the content **XYZ** should be seen always irrespective of the screen size.

I am also giving the navigation bar html code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <div class="row row-content">
                <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar">
                        <li> <a href="#"><b> XYZ </b></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-8">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                             aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                             aria-hidden="true"></span>About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just misplaced your brand anchor tab 'XYZ'. And use `navbar-brand` to your brand.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b> XYZ </b></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <div class="row row-content">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                             aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                             aria-hidden="true"></span>About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contactus.html"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b> XYZ </b></a></li>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                             aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                             aria-hidden="true"></span>About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this.

The thing is you are using the link with class `navbar-brand` in the `navbar-collapse` 
so that's why it is also collapsing.


I hope the problem is solved.

Comment: Better give the jquery link before the bootstrap js to get toggle working.